# Why is there zero moderator accountability on this stack?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer, moderation, deleted-questions

So, I've been participating in the stack for a few months now. And I say the following to emphasize that I understand what it can mean to run a space for online discourse, and that these circles are fraught with all sorts of challenges.
Over the last few years, I participated in multiple forums, moderated a few, and adminned others. Most recently, I was asked to join a mod team, where the community started at about 2-3k and grew to roughly 15 thousand members by the time I decided to move on.

And of all the places I've visited, or participated in, this stack has been probably the most inhospitable and unaccountable online environment I've seen so far. Which is saying something. It's nearly impenetrable for new users, and the 'guidance' to help them navigate the space is insufficient, at best, and actively antagonistic at worst.

Most places have some kind of process for addressing those issues. This community appears to have no such mechanism, the CoC simply had a link to a generic contact queue, which does not explain what to expect, or how any of that works.

I can't imagine the volume of users who come here, post once or twice, and never come back. I'm sure that's perfectly acceptable to some folks, but it shouldn't be the baseline for any healthy community.

After the last experience I had, where a mod not only deleted an answer I provided, for purely punitive reasons, but went on to delete comments critical of their behavior, it seemed like the time to post about this, because unaccountability, and disgruntled people continually leaving, is how this sort of thing keeps occurring, and will keep occurring.

**What is the process for lodging complaints about moderator behavior, and how is that process resolved?**

Comment: If you want to specifically complain about the *misbehaviour* of a moderator on this stack, then the contact form you found on the CoC seems to be the right place. If you wish to discuss what happened and find out where it went haywire, then posting in here is the right way. Also this is not an answer, but a comment; I don't think myself able to properly respond to the query you pose, simply able to comment

Comment: You really do need to link the things that you take issue with, we can't judge behaviour we can't look at.

Comment: After reading some of the comments below, it seems this question is about a specific post rather than a criticism of the community as a whole. If so, could you edit the question in order to get rid of the ambiguity?

Comment: @vincent It is, most certainly, about the community as a whole. I've seen multiple issues that were not great, but the last instance prompted me to ask what the protocol is for this. I have better things to do than deal with drama on stack exchange, so it never seemed worth it, but if these sort of issues are going to crop up repeatedly, it needed to be asked.

Comment: @user49466 --- If this is truly about the forum (and that's those of us who are not mods, as well as those who are!), then I think we all have a right to know of which your complain. To be honest with you, I have not noticed any particular "drama" or "inhospitability" here. I too have been a mod, an admin & an owner of forums in this domain so, yada-yada, I too am familiar with how to deal with these kinds of issues. As Ash said, please link to those threads & behaviours you're taking issue with! We can't judge the behaviour or the situation if we can't see what you're experiencing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the process for lodging complaints about moderator behavior, and how is that process resolved?

The typical process is to start by flagging the post your grievance is related to with a custom moderator flag and describe what you think should be changed. You've got only 600 characters for the custom flag text, so you'll have to be brief, but there's always the option for a moderator to contact you to get more details.

Now, I know what you're thinking; "how can flagging something for moderator attention be the proper way to lodge complaints about moderator behavior?". But it is.

Let's be clear about terminology, though: "moderator", on the Stack Exchange network, typically refers to those users who are either appointed by Stack Exchange (the company) employees to serve as "pro tem" moderators on a site that is still in beta, *or* on graduated sites refers to those users who are elected by the community to serve as moderators. These users are recognizable by having a diamond symbol attached to their name on the site(s) that they are a moderator on, and their profile page will indicate "moderator".

Many *moderation actions* are taken by users who are not *moderators*. There are rather few things that moderators can do which ordinary community members cannot do, though moderators (those with the diamond) can normally do them *unilaterally* rather than having to wait for multiple users from the community to do something. This includes closing questions, deleting posts, and a number of other more or less mundane tasks needed to keep the community on track and free of irrelevant material. It's been likened elsewhere, rather aptly actually, to [being elected to clean the toilets at summer camp](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1442/2533).

If a *moderator* takes an action which you disagree with, then by flagging the post and describing your grievance, you bring this to the attention of [the whole moderator team](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). And while there is nothing in the system to *prevent* it from happening, as a general rule, *moderators are expected to not handle flags that they have a personal interest in*. This can be because it's a flag on their own question or one they've answered, or a flag on an answer they've deleted, or something else. In that case, a different moderator will look at the issue, perhaps discuss it with the moderator who took the original action, and reach some kind of independent conclusion based on the facts at hand, and act on it. There are some situations where it's reasonable for a moderator to review their own actions, but it's rare. (As a corollary to this, if you flag and request a review, precisely because of this process it can take a while before the flag gets validated. Do rest assured that we check every custom flag raised, and stay on top of the others as well.)

If bringing the issue to the attention of the moderator team via a flag does not result in whatever your grievance is being resolved appropriately, then you can escalate the matter further. Typical venues in such cases is to bring it up on the site's Meta (as you have done here, but you'll normally get more positive results by sticking to the facts at hand) or contacting Stack Exchange directly (in which case you *definitely* want to stick to the facts) and request that they review the facts at hand. Just be aware that the people at Stack Exchange are really busy (that's one major reason why there are appointed and community-elected moderators for each site in the network) and that they might not be familiar with the culture of the particular site.

> Why is there zero moderator accountability on this stack?

Well, as explained above, there is plenty of accountability if you raise an issue. Also, moderators routinely cross-check each others' actions, and will discuss among themselves if they see a moderator doing something strange. Moderator actions are also at times reviewed by Stack Exchange employees, and in cases of gross overstepping of bounds, there have actually been cases of moderators being stripped of their diamonds (and corresponding power) for violating the trust ultimately placed in them.

Comment: thank you for the response, and your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're talking about [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/121111/40408), this is almost the definition of a link-only answer, see point five of the list for [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers). It relies on a series of links to external sources without given any information as to the content of those links, as it sits in the deletion queue it absolutely deserves to be there. If a Mod hadn't gotten to it first it would have been cut out by votes in the low quality content queue in short order. I can't speak to deleted comments but given the tone you took in what was left of the comment string I'm going to guess that you violated the [be nice directive](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) of the site. Such comments can and will also be culled without the need for any direct moderator input.

Comment: That is not correct. My answer was as follows: "You'd likely want some sort of [..] that uses [...] and some sort of [...]" **I then provided supplemental links.** That is the answer which was claimed to be link only, which it **clearly is not**. And I know that it is not because **the exact same content with the links removed was deemed acceptable**. An answer cannot rationally be "link only" if it suddenly becomes acceptable when the links are removed. On top of that, another user provided an answer **with even less detail** which was not deleted. (Continued)

Comment: "relies on external sources" not solely contains external sources just relies on them which that answer does as there is no synopsis of the link content in the answer, it therefore relies on the external sites.

Comment: In addition, the response was not deleted until I pointed out the problems with the decision. It wasn't deleted for being "link only". It was deleted because I made no reservations about disagreement. And furthermore, additional comments on the *new answer* were deleted, and are no longer present at all. I'm not here for additional review of the comment thread. There's no way that "You'd likely want some sort of [..] that uses [...] and some sort of [...]" can be deemed link only, but someone replying with "the answer is certainly [x]" can be deemed **by a different standard** (cont)

Comment: The decision is not, at all, justifiable, and the mod in question chose to delete the answer outright, without so much as a word about even more egregious "problems" in comparable responses. Given the lack of internal consistency in that standard, I have zero desire to revisit that. What I do want to understand is what, if any, accountability process is present.

Comment: Yes it is, totally justified.

Comment: Again: **An answer cannot rationally be "link only" if it becomes acceptable when the links are removed.** If an answer is "link only" that implies there would either be no content without links, or, at best, the content is incomprehensible without links. Neither of those things are true. If an answer is acceptable on its own, *which this one was*, then the addition of links is supplemental, not central, to the answer. There is a glaring, and obvious inconsistency, at multiple points here. Nor is that, at all, relevant to my question, which is what mechanisms exist to lodge complaints.

Comment: To be honest, it was edited & deleted & locked & unlocked mostly because *you* were behaving immaturely. Links in an answer are fine. I insert links & images all the time. I can't see your original original answer, so can't comment on that. But clearly, you went off the rails with your "offending the mods" bit. That's not a helpful answer and it is quite appropriate for that portion to be edited out. If I'd seen your answer, I would have edited it out & I'm not even a mod! You shot yourself in the foot by insisting on rolling back. It's no wonder this answer has such a long edit history!

Comment: @elemtilas **That's not the answer we are referring to.** The tone you are critical of is the result of the original response being deleted, condescension, and having additional comments removed. So yeah, given that, I felt the need to explain to the OP why the response to their question suddenly vanished. And per HDE bothering to have a (shock) respectful conversation, I edited the second answer. Which is exactly what I would have done the first time around if it were handled properly.

Comment: Like I said, I can only comment on the sequellae. Your "explanation" I think was not helpful and would have best been addressed in the comments. That you continue behaving somewhat disrespectfully here doesn't speak well. From the outside, it looks like the mods handled the later parts of the issue very well (editing out the snarky bits) without resorting to insult or negative language. If it helps, undelete the deleted answer and let everyone see!

Comment: @elemtilas Your suggestion that the context would be better addressed in the comments is precisely what I did. The comments were deleted because the mod did not like the criticism. And they cannot be undeleted because they are comments.

Comment: I've been critical, and I have the right and reason to level that critique. Michael addressed my question here, and that's all I needed. I'm tired of seeing rules inequitably applied, and now I understand the process if this becomes an issue in the future. The answer was, literally, identical to the one that was deleted, sans links, so I'll let it stand the way that it is.

Comment: @elemtilas The deleted answer was similar to the current one, but with less elaboration on certain points. (If you want a screenshot, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSd0p.png)

Comment: ^That is the original answer. That was deemed unacceptable. By comparison, my second answer was deemed acceptable, by the same mod: https://imgur.com/a/oD3sxfT

Comment: When one compares the old "unacceptable" answer and the new "acceptable" answer, it is clear that **the removal of the links is the only difference**. To quote a recent LO request: "There's nothing wrong with having links. It's just that links should be to supplemental material and not essential to the question." If they were "essential" he wouldn't have suggested the edit with **identical text**. And if I'm being expected to detail a Tavor, then other answers, like this one: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/121149/49466 should be held to the same standard.

Comment: Shrug. The links are back in, so, all's swell that ends well. Lessons learned: be nice; don't antagonise folks that are trying to help improve your answer. You are correct: that last response is more of a comment than an actual answer. The "opinion page" part of his response has been removed.

Comment: And all this drama for a query that looks to be closed soon for being too opinion based! (And it clearly is *entirely* opinion based!)

Comment: @user49466, the additional answer you refer to went down even harder, heavily downvoted and community deleted. Question is now on hold for being opinion based.

Comment: @separatix That's not the point. The problem is that that answer was left completely unchanged all this time, *while I was held to a different standard*. I was then gaslit for a solid twenty four hours about answers being LO, when the **identical** response was not only suggested by the mod, themself, but accepted by the OP! The *lesson* learned is not: *be nice*, but rather that I should not expect to be treated with respect. The lesson learned is not *that folks are trying to improve my answer*, but that at least one mod prefers a less informative answer that makes them feel in-charge (Cont)

Comment: @user49466 Your original answer would have hit the low quality queue immediately because the bots would have pinged it for "length and content" based on the high percentage of overall characters being used for hyperlink text, the mods being onto it and good at their jobs would have seen it almost immediately and acted appropriately. You decided not to take on their constructive criticism which is is where the issues started.

Comment: @elemtilas and worse yet, that if I actually want those problems taken seriously, I should also expect absolutely **nobody** to view the problem with anything close to objectivity. The internal logic here has never changed: LO questions are so sparse that they do not make sense without the links. Links are central to LO posts. **If the links were central to my post, he would not have proposed the identical text as an acceptable answer**. The mere fact that V2 was his edit directly refutes the reason he used to delete it. These are all extremely valid reasons for me to be frustrated.

Comment: @Ash if that would have gone to the queue **why did that mod propose the same edit**? Nor do I have any assurance, at all, that V2 would have been deleted. It clearly wasn't. And if that version was acceptable, one with additional links, should be, as well.

Comment: @user49466 Not when all it is is links, it is a poor answer without the external data but at least it is an internally complete answer. It's actually less of an answer when the majority of the information in it is in external sources; because those sources can, and do, go away at a moment's notice answers need to include enough information that they can survive external data deletions.

Comment: @ash again: it *cannot* be *all links* if the mod, themself, proposes it as an answer **without the links** That does not make sense.

Comment: @user49466 No it doesn't make sense _to you_, that is not the same thing at all. The content that makes the version with links into a full answer is in the linked articles not the answer, without the links there's a different, less substantial, complete answer.

Comment: @Ash what you consider the *less substantial, complete answer* is the one the **mod** proposed. Have you looked at the linked screens above?

Comment: @ash If my answer is "[xyz] [Here's a link]" and the mod says: "That's too reliant on links, please change it to only [xyz]" That, by definition, means it is *not* reliant on links. It can't be, by the very nature of the proposed edit.  If something is improved by removing links, it cannot, logically, be said to have been dependent on those links in the first place. The mod is stating that the same text, as a standalone, is acceptable.

Comment: @user49466 Yes it is because "xyz link" is not the same answer as "xyz."

Comment: @ash Of course it's not the same: it has no links. If [xyz] [link] is unacceptable, but [xyz] as a standalone *is acceptable* that means  [xyz] was not dependent on the removed links.

Comment: @user49466 No it doesn't, xyz is a terrible answer but is internally complete, is has other problems but it's completeness is not one of them. X-link y-link z-link, which is what your answer actually was, not xyz-link that downplays how much external information you were using, may have more information but because most of it is external it is a less _complete_ answer.

Comment: @Ash The text is identical. *Identical*. If [xyz] is internally complete, it *cannot* be made less complete by the addition of links.

Comment: @user49466 Yes it can because the information is no longer here in the stack it's off-site and it's durability is therefore far more dubious, the answer as posted is no longer internally complete given only the information presented in the answer. The answer with links in it may contain more information overall but less of its total content has actually been posted to the Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: @Ash So now LO is being changed to mean any post where the link content is not summarized in post? This is yet another example of the double standard. Did Cort summarize what a predator, a baneling, or terminator 2 are, in the multiple links he posted here? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121084/creature-design-unkillable-save-by-sacrifice/121161#121161 What you are describing is **not** the definition of LO and is not a standard that is applied across the site. LO is not defined by whether link content is summarized. It is defined by whether the answer can stand on its own.

Comment: *and this answer stood on its own*. We can see that because it is what the mod requested.

Comment: @Ash Link Only. The metric you are using is not referenced anywhere in terms of what defines a LO post.

Comment: @user49466 No and its irritating but Cort's examples are also not necessary to his answer.

Comment: @Ash exactly. And neither are mine. Because when they were removed, the answer was deemed acceptable by the mod.

Comment: @user49466 They are entirely central to [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/121111/40408) as previously stated the two answers are not the same to spite your insistence that they are.

Comment: @Ash and what element of this: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XW2DwQun95s&feature=youtu.be# 53 second video of a bullet curving is *central* to me recommending an aim-assisted high-caliber bullpup rifle?

Comment: @user49466 Because you used it in lieu of an independently complete explanation.

Comment: @Ash so now you're back to asserting that link content needs to be summarized. Which is not what defines "link only", not anywhere in the rules, and not enforced on this site.

Comment: @user49466 Because the lack of a summary _defines_ a link-only answer, as opposed to answer that uses links.

Comment: @Ash **Whether someone *describes* the content of the link is not relevant.** It is not in the rules. It is not in the interpretations of the rules. There are ample examples of users posting links without detailing what those links contain, without those posts being deleted.

Comment: @user49466 Yes it is in the rules "Provide context for links:
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Without the relevant information from the link, a summary if you will, you have not provided a full answer.

Comment: @Ash: The guidance here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers is the only official feedback that touches on ‘link only’ closes. And it simply states: *“barely more than a link to an external site”*. That's a fairly subjective measure, but generally speaking, we all agree that answers such as: *“I think that the best solution is [link]”* is clearly a link-only answer. We can infer the use of this rule, by looking at how its been described in the past.

Comment: For example, here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/113637/can-i-have-droplets-of-fluids-that-arent-well-droplets#comment347585_113639 *“[...]We expect answers to stand on their own **without needing to rely on external sources to remain unchanged***

Comment: We can see from this, and infer from common-sense, that what defines the centrality of a link, and therefore what defines a ‘link only’ question is, **whether the answer can remain functional without the links**.
The example: *“I think that the best solution is [link]”* cannot be understandable without the link. Therefore it is a link-only answer.
A better version would be: *“I think the best solution is [x], here is what [x] looks like when in operation [link].”*
That is **not** a link only answer, because it is still functional and comprehensible without the link.

Comment: @Ash and for the record, your source for that quote https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer are suggestions, not rules. It also includes: *"Pay it forward

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, vote up the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here."* If we're to infer that the contents of that page are considered "rules", this would also be a rule, which it clearly isn't.